# Анимация продавливания плитки в стиле Windows 8

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать подобную анимацию без сторонних библиотек или jQuery. Гифку изъял [отсюда](https://www.pixijs.com/) из следующего раздела:

> Раздел "Created with PixiJS" по ссылке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот моя попытка:

UPD: Сделал эффект для плитки из нескольких изображений (адаптивненько) + тень

```js
let limit = a => Math.sign(a) * Math.min(15, Math.abs(a));

let imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')].map(img => {

  let container = document.createElement('div');
  container.classList.add('card-3d');
  img.parentNode.insertBefore(container, img);
  container.append(img);
  let reqId, tx = 0, ty = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

  function upd() {
      animate();
      x += (tx - x)/9;
      y += (ty - y)/9;
      img.style.transform = `rotatex(${-y}deg) rotatey(${x}deg)`;
      img.style.boxShadow = `${-x/4}px ${-y/4}px 5px 0 #0006`;
  }
  
  function animate() {
      if (Math.abs(tx - x) > 0.01 && Math.abs(ty - y) > 0.01)
        reqId = requestAnimationFrame(upd);
  }
  
  return function(x, y) {
      tx = ty = 0; 
      let r = container.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (r.x < x && r.y < y && r.x + r.width > x && r.y + r.height > y) {
          tx = limit((x - r.x - r.width/2)/4);
          ty = limit((y - r.y - r.height/2)/3);
      } 
      cancelAnimationFrame(reqId);
      animate();
  }
});

addEventListener('mousemove', e => imgs.forEach(i => i(e.x, e.y)));
```

```css
.card-3d {
    perspective: 1000px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/44/200/150" >
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/45/200/150" >
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/46/200/150" >
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/47/200/150" ><br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/48/415/305" >
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/49/415/305" ><br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/43/415/305" >
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/42/415/305" >
```

Comment: Когда наводишь мышкой и убираешь, значения продолжают меняться, но визуально ничего не происходит... это как?

Comment: типо слишком большие числа?

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex наоборот маленькие, почти 0

Comment: А как оно анимируется? Функция upd постоянно вызывается что ли? Даже когда  tx и  ty не обновляется?

Comment: красиво ...хороший пример

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex дааа, это слегка не оптимально, можно проверочку добавить. если делать из этого плагин, то это необходимо.

Comment: +1, но не оптимально, `requestAnimationFrame` будет работать даже тогда, когда ничего не происходит, решение хорошее

Comment: @meine все верно, это для упрощения ответа, в продакшене надо звать кадры только если дельта больше порогового значения. и я сейчас свежим взглядом смотрю что перемудрил с Mathерью

Answer (score 6):

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.box-wrapper')
var box = document.querySelector('.box')
var wrapperRect, elementLeftPlusElementHalfWidth, elementLeftPlusElementHalfHeight,
    elementLeft, elementRight, elementTop, elementBottom, x, y

init()

wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleaveHandler)

function mouseMoveHandler({
  pageX,
  pageY
}) {
  if (pageX > elementLeft && pageX < elementRight)
    x = (pageX - elementLeftPlusElementHalfWidth) * 0.04

  if (pageY > elementTop && pageY < elementBottom)
    y = -(pageY - elementLeftPlusElementHalfHeight) * 0.04

  box.style.transform = `rotateX(${Math.round(y)}deg) rotateY(${Math.round(x)}deg)`
}

function mouseleaveHandler() {
  box.style.transform = 'rotateX(0) rotateY(0)'
}

function init() {
  wrapperRect = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
  ({
    left: elementLeft,
    right: elementRight,
    top: elementTop,
    bottom: elementBottom
  } = wrapperRect)

  elementLeftPlusElementHalfWidth = elementLeft + wrapperRect.width / 2
  elementLeftPlusElementHalfHeight = elementTop + wrapperRect.height / 2
}

addEventListener('resize', () => init())
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: #38404e;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-wrapper {
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.box {
  width: 490px;
  height: 390px;
  background-color: #465162;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.box__cover {
  background-image: url('https://www.pixijs.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/HeinekenGoplaces-540x312.jpg');
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box__footer {
  height: 25%;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  align-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text-2 {
  color: #BDBDBD;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box__cover"></div>
    <footer class="box__footer">
      <div class="text-1 ">Heineken Go Places</div>
      <div class="text-2">Cloud Factory</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: тоже не хилый пример ...главное работает